# Drop list menu selectpicker printed by php and doesn't interact with jquary

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I created a drop-down menu type 'select picker'. This list is printed from a controller-function that is called by a jQuery.

The menu has been called and the result appeared well. the problem the drop down menu appeared as no style and doesn't interact if the another option selected.

[image: First list menu get the DB but no style]

- select picker printed into the below div with ID [itemresult]

HTML

```
<form id="myWHForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="txtItemId" value="0">


                            <div id="itemresult"></div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="warehouse" class="label-control col-md-3">Warehouse</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <select class="selectpicker" required data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="Warehouse" id="Warehouse">
                                        <?php foreach($wh as $w):?>
                                            <option value= "<?php echo $w->w_id;?>" ><?php echo $w->w_name;?></option>
                                        <?php endforeach;?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

jQuery/Ajax [fetch the drop menu from the controller and take another action if the an option of the select picker picked]

```
$(function() {

load_item_data();

function load_item_data() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ItemSettings/load_item_data",
                method: "POST",
                success:function (data) {
                    $('#itemresult').html(data);
                }
            })
        }


$('#item_wh').change(function(){
            var wh_result = $(this).val();
            //$(#item_wh).val();
            if(wh_result != '')
            {
                load_wh_data(wh_result);
            }
        });

});
```

Controller

```
function load_item_data(){
        $output = '';
        $data = $this->m->load_item_data();
        $output .='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="item" class="label-control col-md-3">Item</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <select class="selectpicker" required data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="item_wh" id="item_wh">
                                            <option disabled selected>Select Item</option>
                                            ';


        if($data->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($data->result() as $row)
            {
                $output .='
                
                <option value ="'.$row->s_id.'">'.$row->s_name.'</option>
                ';
            }

        }

        $output.='
        
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        ';
        echo $output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dropdown is generated dynamically chaNGE YOUR SCRIPT FUNCTION AS BELOW

```
$(document).on("change","#item_wh", function()
{
    var wh_result = $(this).val();
    //$(#item_wh).val();
    if(wh_result != '')
    {
        load_wh_data(wh_result);
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery Worked fine, I'm still facing a problem with selectpicker style. I have no idea why the first drop menu doesn't take the style like the warehouse input [I wish the IMG clearly explain the issue].

Comment: The CSS issue solved by adding this line  `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` , Thank You for your help